# Issues accessing JSF generated element by id

Tags: selenium, jsf

```html
<h:body>
  <h:form id="mainForm">
    <h:inputText id="nameInput"></h:inputText>
    <h:commandButton id="submitBtn" action="welcome.xhtml"/>   
  </h:form>
</h:body>
```

```js
browser.find_element_by_id("mainForm:nameInput").send_keys("qwerty")
browser.find_element_by_id("mainForm:submitBtn").click()
```

When I am trying to find the element by id from xhtml page I am getting this error.

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="mainForm:nameInput"]"}

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML instead of the unprocessed XHTML to prevent answers about the form ID not being part of the input ID.

Comment: Looks like the id is `nameInput` and not `mainForm:nameInput`; same for the other one.

Comment: @SiKing Incorrect. JSF generates the id based on the hierarchy of the component tree.